# Can't access db after adding to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, heroku-postgres

I can't access my Postgres tables since putting my app on Heroku. I checked the logs with `heroku logs --tail` and saw this error

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist`

I've run as many different `rake` combinations of `drop` `create` `migrate` `seed`, and `reset` as I can think of with no luck.

I created a new endpoint on that app (`/api/v1/testing/`) and I was able to access that endpoint with no problem.

I am still able to access all of the tables on the db locally when I run `rails s`.

I don't know which files from my app would be helpful to solve this problem  but I am happy to add any detail that would be helpful.

Comment: did you do `heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_app_name`? (Replacing, `your_app_name`, naturally.)

Comment: no... no I hadn't.  That, well,... yea, that worked. Thank you.

Comment: Added as an answer so you can upvote/accept as you see fit.

Comment: Hm. No upvote/accept. Future searchers are so sad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_app_name
```

(replacing `your_app_name`, naturally.)